# Validate information between 2 tables - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables that I need to validate some information, for example:

**Table A (GTM_LICENSE_LINE):**

```
License Nº - License Line Nº
123 - 123_1
123 - 123_2
```

**Table B (GTM_LICENSE_LINE_ITEM):**

```
License Line Nº - Item Nº
123_1 - XXX
```

However, I need to validate if there are any licenses lines without a Item nº associated (*all lines must have only one Item nº*).

My expected result would be "1" if the condition is true (all license line have an associated item) or null if the condition is false. I'm trying to use LEFT JOIN w/ GROUP BY but it's not working for me.

```
SELECT u.GTM_LICENSE_LINE_GID 
FROM GTM_LICENSE_LINE I 
LEFT JOIN GTM_LICENSE_LINE_ITEM U 
    ON I.LICENSE_LINE_GID = U.GTM_LICENSE_LINE_GID 
WHERE i.LICENSE_GID = 'ELEB.L001' 
  AND U.GTM_LICENSE_LINE_GID is null 
GROUP BY U.GTM_LICENSE_LINE_GID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

How can I do this using Oracle SQL? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Add some more sample data and also the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Hey, not as comments. Edit the question instead.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i'm new here :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably after something like this:

```
WITH table1 AS (SELECT 123 License_num, '123_1' license_line_num FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 123 License_num, '123_2' license_line_num FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 456 License_num, '456_1' license_line_num FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 456 License_num, '456_2' license_line_num FROM dual),
     table2 AS (SELECT '123_1' license_line_num, 'XXX' item_num FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT '456_1' license_line_num, 'YYY' item_num FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT '456_2' license_line_num, 'ZZZ' item_num FROM dual)
SELECT t1.license_num,
       t1.license_line_num,
       MIN(CASE WHEN t2.license_line_num IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.license_num) all_lines_present
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.license_line_num = t2.license_line_num
ORDER BY t1.license_num, t1.license_line_num;

LICENSE_NUM LICENSE_LINE_NUM ALL_LINES_PRESENT
----------- ---------------- -----------------
        123 123_1                            0
        123 123_2                            0
        456 456_1                            1
        456 456_2                            1
```

I'm assuming here that there is a unique constraint on table2 where you can have at most one row for each license_line_num.

This works by outer joining the second table to the first (which shouldn't produce any duplicate lines). Then we use a conditional aggregate function (in this case, MIN) to determine that if there is a value from the second table present, we output a 1 otherwise a 0 for each row, before finding the lowest value.

That way, if any of the rows is missing an item row, the lowest value across all rows for each license_num will be 0.

---

ETA: If you just want a single row per license_num, you can just use a conditional aggregate function instead, e.g.:

```
WITH table1 AS (SELECT 123 License_num, '123_1' license_line_num FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 123 License_num, '123_2' license_line_num FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 456 License_num, '456_1' license_line_num FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 456 License_num, '456_2' license_line_num FROM dual),
     table2 AS (SELECT '123_1' license_line_num, 'XXX' item_num FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT '456_1' license_line_num, 'YYY' item_num FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT '456_2' license_line_num, 'ZZZ' item_num FROM dual)
SELECT license_num,
       CASE WHEN all_lines_present = 1 THEN 1 END all_lines_present
FROM   (SELECT t1.license_num,
               MIN(CASE WHEN t2.license_line_num IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) all_lines_present
        FROM   table1 t1
               LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.license_line_num = t2.license_line_num
        GROUP BY t1.license_num)
ORDER BY license_num;

LICENSE_NUM ALL_LINES_PRESENT
----------- -----------------
        123 
        456                 1
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I think it should work.
Just a question: If the condition is not true, is it possible to not return any value instead of returning 0?

Comment: Sure, just throw a case statement around the aggregate function result to set it to null if the value is 0. E.g. `case when min(...)... = 0 then null else min(...)... end`. To save typing the aggregate function out more than once, you could also put the query in a subquery and use the case statement in the outer query, which would allow you to use the column alias for the aggregate function column - e.g. `select ..., case when all_lines_present = 0 then .... end from (select ..., min(...) ... )`

Comment: Great! Just one more question: Is it possible to return only 1 result for each LICENSE_NUM instead of LICENSE_LINE_NUM? I mean, I need just one result for each LICENSE NUM but in the current query is returning accordingly to the qty of my License Lines.

Comment: I've updated my question to provide that answer. This is why we asked you to provide the expected result in your question - it would have meant far less faffing around when trying to answer your question.

Comment: Sure, you're right. Sorry about this and thanks a lot for your help!